# OpenCV Multi-threading giving errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, ubuntu

I am running OpenCV code on multiple threads in the following fashion:

```
std::thread t1(runOnSingleCamera, alphaFile, featureToUse, classifier,0);
  std::thread t2(runOnSingleCamera, betaFile, featureToUse, classifier,1);
  std::thread t3(runOnSingleCamera, gammaFile, featureToUse, classifier,2);
  std::thread t4(runOnSingleCamera, deltaFile, featureToUse, classifier,3);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
```

This compiles fine, but when I run it I get a variety of errors, and it even occasionally works...

Here is a sample of some of the errors I get:

```
tom@thinkpad:~/Documents/Project/reidThermal/src$ ./main -d=1 -c=0 -f=1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
tom@thinkpad:~/Documents/Project/reidThermal/src$ ./main -d=1 -c=0 -f=1

(betaInput.webm:8571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'CvImageWidget'

(betaInput.webm:8571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'CvImageWidget'

(betaInput.webm:8571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'CvImageWidget'

(betaInput.webm:8571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'CvImageWidget'

(betaInput.webm:8571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_new: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GTK_TYPE_WIDGET)' failed

(betaInput.webm:8571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_new: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GTK_TYPE_WIDGET)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
tom@thinkpad:~/Documents/Project/reidThermal/src$ ./main -d=1 -c=0 -f=1

(alphaInput.webm:8593): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'CvImageWidget' to 'CvImageWidget'

** (alphaInput.webm:8593): CRITICAL **: void cvImageWidget_size_allocate(GtkWidget*, GtkAllocation*): assertion 'CV_IS_IMAGE_WIDGET (widget)' failed

** (alphaInput.webm:8593): CRITICAL **: void cvImageWidget_realize(GtkWidget*): assertion 'CV_IS_IMAGE_WIDGET (widget)' failed
**
Gtk:ERROR:/build/gtk+2.0-KsZKkB/gtk+2.0-2.24.30/gtk/gtkwidget.c:8861:gtk_widget_real_map: assertion failed: (gtk_widget_get_realized (widget))
Aborted (core dumped)
tom@thinkpad:~/Documents/Project/reidThermal/src$ ./main -d=1 -c=0 -f=1
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:720: Unable to find include file: "apps/ff.rc"

(betaInput.webm:8615): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'CvImageWidget'

(betaInput.webm:8615): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'CvImageWidget'

(betaInput.webm:8615): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_new: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GTK_TYPE_WIDGET)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Has anyone seen this before/know what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Running using gdb gives the following:

```
Thread 4 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffdb7fe700 (LWP 29317)]
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I am on the most up to date version of Ubuntu using the most up to date version of OpenCV at the time of asking.

Full code below as requested, it is very long and made up of multiple elements, I imagine the issue would be early or in the declarations, or possibly an incompatability with the imshow function:

```
int runOnSingleCamera(String file, int featureToUse, int classifier, int cameraID) 
{
    //enable velocity 
    int timeSteps = 0;

  string windowName = file; // window name

  Mat img, outputImage, foreground; // image objects
  VideoCapture cap;

  bool keepProcessing = true;   // loop control flag
  unsigned char  key;           // user input
  int  EVENT_LOOP_DELAY = 40;   // delay for GUI window, 40 ms equates to 1000ms/25fps = 40ms per frame

  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  int width = 40;
  int height = 100;
  int learning = 1000;
  int padding = 40; 

  // if command line arguments are provided try to read image/video_name
  // otherwise default to capture from attached H/W camera
  if((cap.open(file) == true))
  {
        // create window object (use flag=0 to allow resize, 1 to auto fix size)
        namedWindow(windowName, 1);

        // create background / foreground Mixture of Gaussian (MoG) model
        Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> MoG = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500,25,false);

        HOGDescriptor hog;
        hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

        CascadeClassifier cascade = CascadeClassifier(CASCADE_TO_USE);

    Ptr<SuperpixelSEEDS> seeds;

        // start main loop
      while(keepProcessing)
        {
          int64 timeStart = getTickCount();

            if (cap.isOpened())
          {
                cap >> img;

                if(img.empty())
                {
                    std::cerr << "End of video file reached" << std::endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
                outputImage = img.clone();

                cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            }
          else
          {
              // if not a capture object set event delay to zero so it waits
              // indefinitely (as single image file, no need to loop)
              EVENT_LOOP_DELAY = 0;
          }

          // update background model and get background/foreground
          MoG->apply(img, foreground, (double)(1.0/learning));

          //imshow("old foreground", foreground);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////SUPERPIXELS
          int useSuperpixels = 0;

          if(useSuperpixels == 1)
            {
              Mat seedMask, labels, result;

              result = img.clone();

              int width = img.size().width;
            int height = img.size().height;

            seeds = createSuperpixelSEEDS(width, height, 1, 2000, 10, 2, 5, true);

          seeds->iterate(img, 10);

            seeds->getLabels(labels);

            vector<int> counter(seeds->getNumberOfSuperpixels(),0);
            vector<int> numberOfPixelsPerSuperpixel(seeds->getNumberOfSuperpixels(),0);

            vector<bool> useSuperpixel(seeds->getNumberOfSuperpixels(),false);

            for(int i = 0; i<foreground.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<foreground.cols; j++)
                {
                    numberOfPixelsPerSuperpixel[labels.at<int>(i,j)] += 1;
                    if(foreground.at<unsigned char>(i,j)==255)
                    {
                        counter[labels.at<int>(i,j)] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<counter.size(); i++)
            {
                if(counter[i]/numberOfPixelsPerSuperpixel[i] > 0.0001)
                {
                    useSuperpixel[i] = true;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<foreground.rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<foreground.cols; j++)
                {
                    if(useSuperpixel[labels.at<int>(i,j)] == true)
                    {
                        foreground.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = 255;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreground.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            else
            {
              // perform erosion - removes boundaries of foreground object
              erode(foreground, foreground, Mat(),Point(),1);

              // perform morphological closing
              dilate(foreground, foreground, Mat(),Point(),5);
              erode(foreground, foreground, Mat(),Point(),1);
            }
          //imshow("foreground", foreground);

          // get connected components from the foreground
          findContours(foreground, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

          // iterate through all the top-level contours,
          // and get bounding rectangles for them (if larger than given value)

          for(int idx = 0; idx >=0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
          {
                Rect r = boundingRect(contours[idx]);

                // adjust bounding rectangle to be padding% larger
                // around the object
                r.x = max(0, r.x - (int) (padding/100.0 * (double) r.width));
                r.y = max(0, r.y - (int) (padding/100.0 * (double) r.height));

                r.width = min(img.cols - 1, (r.width + 2 * (int) (padding/100.0 * (double) r.width)));
                r.height = min(img.rows - 1, (r.height + 2 * (int) (padding/100.0 * (double) r.height)));

                // draw rectangle if greater than width/height constraints and if
                // also still inside image
                if ((r.width >= width) && (r.height >= height) && (r.x + r.width < img.cols) && (r.y + r.height < img.rows))
                {
                  vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;

                  Mat roi = outputImage(r);

                  if (classifier == 1)
                  {
                        //changing last parameter helps deal with multiple rectangles per person
                        if (cameraID == 3)
                        {
                            hog.detectMultiScale(roi, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 5);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hog.detectMultiScale(roi, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(64,64), 1.05, 5);
                        }
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                    if (cameraID == 3)
                    {
                        cascade.detectMultiScale(roi, found, 1.1, 4, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(32,32));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cascade.detectMultiScale(roi, found, 1.1, 4, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(64,64));
                    }
                  }

                  for(size_t i = 0; i < found.size(); i++ )
                  {
                        Rect rec = found[i];

                        rec.x += r.x;
                        rec.y += r.y;

                        size_t j;
                        // Do not add small detections inside a bigger detection.
                        for ( j = 0; j < found.size(); j++ )
                        {
                          if ( j != i && (rec & found[j]) == rec )
                          {
                              break;
                          }
                        }

                        if (j == found.size())
                        {
                          found_filtered.push_back(rec);
                        }
                  }
                  for (size_t i = 0; i < found_filtered.size(); i++)
                  {
                        Rect rec = found_filtered[i];

                        // The HOG/Cascade detector returns slightly larger rectangles than the real objects,
                        // so we slightly shrink the rectangles to get a nicer output.
                        rec.x += rec.width*0.1;
                        rec.width = rec.width*0.8;
                        rec.y += rec.height*0.1;
                        rec.height = rec.height*0.8;
                        // rectangle(img, rec.tl(), rec.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 3);

                        Point2f center = Point2f(float(rec.x + rec.width/2.0), float(rec.y + rec.height/2.0));

                        Mat regionOfInterest;

                        Mat regionOfInterestOriginal = img(rec);
                        //Mat regionOfInterestOriginal = img(r);

                        Mat regionOfInterestForeground  = foreground(rec);
                        //Mat regionOfInterestForeground = foreground(r);

                        bitwise_and(regionOfInterestOriginal, regionOfInterestForeground, regionOfInterest);

                        Mat clone = regionOfInterest.clone();

                        resize(clone, regionOfInterest, Size(64,128), CV_INTER_CUBIC);

                        imshow("roi", regionOfInterest);

                        double huMoments[7];
                        vector<double> hu(7);
                        Mat hist;
                        vector<float> descriptorsValues;

                        Mat feature;

                        if(featureToUse == 1) //HuMoments
                        {
                          vector<vector<Point> > contoursHu;
                          vector<Vec4i> hierarchyHu;

                          findContours(regionOfInterest, contoursHu, hierarchyHu, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                          double largestSize,size;
                          int largestContour;

                          for(int i = 0; i < contoursHu.size(); i++)
                          {
                                size = contoursHu[i].size();

                                if(size > largestSize)
                                {
                                  largestSize = size;
                                  largestContour = i;
                                }
                          }
                          Moments contourMoments;

                          contourMoments = moments(contoursHu[largestContour]);

                          HuMoments(contourMoments, huMoments);

                          hu.assign(huMoments,huMoments+7);

              feature = Mat(hu);
              feature = feature.t();
                        }
                        else if(featureToUse == 2) //HistogramOfIntensities
                        {
                          int histSize = 16;    // bin size - need to determine which pixel threshold to use
                          float range[] = {0,255};
                          const float *ranges[] = {range};
                          int channels[] = {0, 1};

                          calcHist(&regionOfInterest, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, ranges, true, false);

                          feature = hist.clone();
                          feature = feature.t();
                        }

                        else if(featureToUse == 3) //HOG
                        {
                          //play with these parameters to change HOG size 
                          cv::HOGDescriptor descriptor(Size(64, 128), Size(16, 16), Size(16, 16), Size(16, 16), 4, -1, 0.2, true, 64);

                          descriptor.compute(regionOfInterest, descriptorsValues);

                          feature = Mat(descriptorsValues);
                          feature = feature.t();
                        }

                        else if(featureToUse == 4) //Correlogram
                        {                   
                            Mat correlogram(8,8,CV_64F);
                            Mat occurances(8,8,CV_8U);

                            int xIntensity, yIntensity;

                            for(int i = 0; i<regionOfInterest.rows; i++)
                            {
                                for(int j = 0; j<regionOfInterest.cols; j++)
                                {
                                    xIntensity = floor(regionOfInterest.at<unsigned char>(i,j)/32);

                                    for(int k = i; k<regionOfInterest.rows; k++)
                                    {
                                        for(int l = 0; l<regionOfInterest.cols; l++)
                                        {
                                            if((k == i && l > j) || k > i)
                                            {
                                                yIntensity = floor(regionOfInterest.at<unsigned char>(k,l)/32);

                                                correlogram.at<double>(xIntensity,yIntensity) += (norm(Point(i,j)-Point(k,l)));
                                                correlogram.at<double>(yIntensity,xIntensity) += (norm(Point(i,j)-Point(k,l)));

                                                occurances.at<unsigned char>(xIntensity,yIntensity) += 1;
                                                occurances.at<unsigned char>(yIntensity,xIntensity) += 1;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //average it out
                            for(int i = 0; i<correlogram.rows; i++)
                            {
                                for(int j = 0; j<correlogram.cols; j++)
                                {
                                    correlogram.at<double>(i,j) = occurances.at<unsigned char>(i,j);
                                }
                            }

                            feature = correlogram.reshape(1,1);
                        }
                        else if(featureToUse == 5) //Flow
                        {

                        }

                        feature.convertTo(feature, CV_64F);

                        normalize(feature, feature, 1, 0, NORM_L1, -1, Mat());
                        cout << "New Feature" << endl << feature << endl;

                        //classify first target
                        if(targets.size() == 0) //if first target found
                        {
                          Person person(0, center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                          person.kalmanCorrect(center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                          Rect p = person.kalmanPredict();

                          person.updateFeatures(feature);

                          person.setCurrentCamera(cameraID);

                          rectangle(outputImage, p.tl(), p.br(), cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);

                          char str[200];
                          sprintf(str,"Person %d",person.getIdentifier());

                          putText(outputImage, str, center, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,0));

                          targets.push_back(person);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vector<double> mDistances;
                            bool singleEntry = false;

                            for(int i = 0; i<targets.size(); i++)
                            {
                                if(targets[i].getFeatures().rows == 1)
                                {
                                    singleEntry = true;
                                }
                            }

                            for(int i = 0; i<targets.size(); i++)
                            {
                                Mat covar, mean;
                                Mat data = targets[i].getFeatures();

                                calcCovarMatrix(data,covar,mean,CV_COVAR_NORMAL|CV_COVAR_ROWS);

                                // cout << i << " data" << endl << data << endl;

                                // cout << i << " Covar" << endl << covar << endl;

                                // cout << i << " mean" << endl << mean << endl;

                                double mDistance;

                                if(singleEntry == false)
                                {
                                    Mat invCovar;

                                    invert(covar,invCovar,DECOMP_SVD);

                                    mDistance = Mahalanobis(feature,mean,invCovar);

                                    cout << i << " Mahalanobis Distance" << endl << mDistance << endl;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    mDistance = norm(feature,mean,NORM_L1);

                                    cout << i << " Norm Distance" << endl << mDistance << endl;
                                }
                                mDistances.push_back(mDistance);
                            }

                            Mat test = Mat(mDistances); 
                            cout << "Distances" << endl << test << endl;

                            double sum = 0.0;
                            for(int i = 0; i<mDistances.size(); i++)
                            {
                                sum += mDistances[i];
                            }
                            for(int i = 0; i<mDistances.size(); i++)
                            {
                                mDistances[i] = sum/mDistances[i];
                            }

                            normalize(mDistances,mDistances,1,0,NORM_L1,-1,Mat());

                            Mat probabilities = Mat(mDistances);

                            cout << "Probabilities" << endl << probabilities << endl;

                            //special case to classify second target
                        if(targets.size() == 1)
                        {
                            if(fabs(center.x-targets[0].getLastPosition().x)<100 and fabs(center.y-targets[0].getLastPosition().y)<100)
                            {
                                targets[0].kalmanCorrect(center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                                  Rect p = targets[0].kalmanPredict();

                                targets[0].updateFeatures(feature);

                                targets[0].setCurrentCamera(cameraID);

                                  rectangle(outputImage, p.tl(), p.br(), cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);

                                  char str[200];
                                  sprintf(str,"Person %d",targets[0].getIdentifier());

                                  putText(outputImage, str, center, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,0));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Person person(1, center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                                  person.kalmanCorrect(center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                                  Rect p = person.kalmanPredict();

                                person.updateFeatures(feature);

                                person.setCurrentCamera(cameraID);

                                  rectangle(outputImage, p.tl(), p.br(), cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);

                                  char str[200];
                                  sprintf(str,"Person %d",person.getIdentifier());

                                  putText(outputImage, str, center, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,0));

                                  targets.push_back(person);
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            double greatestProbability = 0.0;
                            int identifier = 0;

                            double min, max;
                                Point min_loc, max_loc;
                                minMaxLoc(probabilities, &min, &max, &min_loc, &max_loc);

                                greatestProbability = max;
                                identifier = max_loc.y;

                                cout << greatestProbability << " at " << identifier << endl;

                            if(greatestProbability >= 0.5)
                            {
                                targets[identifier].kalmanCorrect(center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                                  Rect p = targets[identifier].kalmanPredict();

                                targets[identifier].updateFeatures(feature);

                                targets[identifier].setCurrentCamera(cameraID);

                                  rectangle(outputImage, p.tl(), p.br(), cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);

                                  char str[200];
                                  sprintf(str,"Person %d",targets[identifier].getIdentifier());

                                  putText(outputImage, str, center, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,0));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int identifier = targets.size();
                                  Person person(identifier, center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                                  person.kalmanCorrect(center.x, center.y, timeSteps, rec.width, rec.height);

                                  Rect p = person.kalmanPredict();

                                person.updateFeatures(feature);

                                person.setCurrentCamera(cameraID);

                                  rectangle(outputImage, p.tl(), p.br(), cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);

                                  char str[200];
                                  sprintf(str,"Person %d",person.getIdentifier());

                                  putText(outputImage, str, center, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,0));

                                  targets.push_back(person);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                  rectangle(outputImage, r, Scalar(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0);
                }
          }
          // display image in window
          imshow(windowName, outputImage);

      key = waitKey((int) std::max(2.0, EVENT_LOOP_DELAY - (((getTickCount() - timeStart) / getTickFrequency())*1000)));

      if (key == 'x')
    {
            // if user presses "x" then exit
            std::cout << "Keyboard exit requested : exiting now - bye!" << std::endl;
            keepProcessing = false;
      }
      timeSteps += 1;
      }
      // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
      // all OK : main returns 0
      return 0;
    }
    // not OK : main returns -1
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that you're abusing some feature of OpenCV that doesn't support running in a multi-threaded environment, or else you're not making proper use of control mechanisms such as mutexes and monitors to restrict access to critical sections of your code to one thread at a time. We won't be able to tell you what you're doing wrong unless you share more of your code though. From your log it seems as though some sort of initialization is being run more than once.

---

From your code and your log, two things come to mind:

1. Are you accidentally trying to access video capture hardware on multiple threads?
2. Maybe creating a new window causes initialization of something in GTK. Try to create your windows on the main thread, see if it helps. Note that OpenCV or not, having more than one thread for your UI is a bad idea.

If none of this helps, try adding some log output to your code so we can be sure which line is causing the errors.

---

So it was #2 after all. To fix it, you must move all the namedWindow calls to the main thread. Afterwards, if it still fails on the imshow calls, you'll have to move that to the main thread as well. You'll need a condition variable for each thread, and global variables which the threads write to and the main thread uses to update the windows. I'd provide the code, but I don't know much about c++ concurrency. You can read more about this task here: [waiting thread until a condition has been occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974829/waiting-thread-until-a-condition-has-been-occurred)

Comment: I have no mutexes or monitors at this time, but the only thing that is shared between the threads is a global vector, but I had the impression that this would result in incorrect results rather than runtime errors? I can post the full code if you want, but it is very long.

Comment: Neither me nor anyone else can say more with the code you provided. Do post more of it. A global vector will, as you say, at worst cause logic errors if written to simultaneously, not segfaults.

Comment: Note that aside from your own variables, the libraries you use may make use of global variables. This will result in concurrency errors.

Comment: <s>A global vector will, as you say, at worst cause logic errors if written to simultaneously, not segfaults.</s> Scratch that, I was thinking of OpenCV vectors. An std::vector will cause segfaults if written to simultaneously, because it may try to reallocate memory, invalidating the memory it was using previously, while another thread may attempt to use that memory.

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense, do you have any suggestions for mitigating this? I'm new to multithreading

Comment: Also, I have just tried moving the global vector to be local for each call of the function, and am still getting similar errors to those posted in the main question

Comment: Added gdb output to original question, will now try moving my window creations

Comment: Tried simply removing all of my imshow and namedwindow calls, and it now seems to work, would you be able to elaborate more on how I would create all 4 windows on the main thread?