# Check if a thread is finished to send another param to it

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wanna to check if a thread job has been finished to call it again and send another parameter to that. The code is sth like this:

```
void SendMassage(double Speed)
{
    Sleep(200);
    cout << "Speed:" << Speed << endl;

}

int main() {

    int Speed_1 = 0;
    thread f(SendMassage, Speed_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Sleep(20);

        if (?)
        {
            another call of thread // If last thread done then call it again, otherwise not.
        }

        Speed_1++;
    }

}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You can verify the thread has not finished yet, but this will tell you nothing about its state at the next moment (when you actually try to send it something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, e.g., an *atomic flag* to indicate that the thread has finished:

```
std::atomic<bool> finished_flag{false};

void SendMassage(double Speed) {
   Sleep(200);
   cout << "Speed:" << Speed << endl;
   finished_flag = true;    
}

int main() {    
   int Speed_1 = 0;
   thread f(SendMassage, Speed_1);

   while (Speed_1 < 50) {
      Sleep(20);    
      if (finished_flag) {
         f.join();
         finished_flag = false;             
         f = std::thread(SendMassage, Speed_1);
      }          
      Speed_1++;    
   }
   f.join();
}
```

Working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BrEMHFvlInshBy5V

---

Note that I assumed that, according to your code, you don't want to block when checking whether the thread `f` has finished. Otherwise, simply call `f.join()`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, your answer helped me define finished_flag to use it between my threads. But I did not get why you call f.joine() in if loop? And also in the last line of code?

Comment: @Rasoul Because you have to call either `f.join()` or `f.detach()` on the `std::thread` object that encapsulates an underlying _thread of execution_. That's how threads have been designed in C++.

Comment: Note, however, that this does not actually answer the question that was asked. This code waits for a thread to terminate, then starts a **new thread**. The question was about reusing the **same thread**. I don't know if that distinction is important; since the answer was accepted, probably not.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, it's not clear from the question whether OP wants to reuse the _thread of execution_ or the `std::thread` object. My code does the latter.

Comment: @Pete Becker Yes, My question was about start a new thread. But if the last thread is finished, starting a new thread is equal to reusing the same one. Am I right?

Comment: @Rasoul -- "equal to reusing" -- yes and no. If you reuse an existing thread, thread-local objects don't get reinitialized -- they keep their old values. If that matters, it can be a problem. That aside, reusing a thread rather than starting a new one is mostly about performance; reusing an already-existing thread is faster. That's the logic behind using thread pools.

Comment: @PeteBecker --"they keep their old values"-- What about a finished thread? If we check that our thread is finished and then call it with new parameters (just like what I want to do in my question) it should use last params.

Comment: @PeteBecker I did not get why you changed your first code (that one that was written with for loop). I think that was more compatible with my question.

Comment: @Rasoul -- sorry, I confused you. A thread-local variable is sort of like a static variable, but with a different instance in each thread. As long as the thread exists, its thread-local variables continue to exist and have whatever values they were most recently set to. If that doesn't make sense, just ignore it; you aren't using thread-local variables, so their behavior isn't important to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait untill a thread has finished it's job without using Sleep, you neeed to call it's join method, like so

```
thread t(SendMassage, Speed_1);
t.join();
//Code here will start executing after returning from join
```

You can read more about it here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

About sending another parameter, I think the best way would be splitting it into another function that you would call after this thread has been joined, if you need some information about something that's known only inside the function, you could create a class that would store that information in it's fields, and use it in the function you're threading.

Answer (score 0):

The possibly most simple way of doing so is just [`join`ing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the thread. Nothing clever, but...

OK, but why would you then want to have another thread at all if your main thread passes all its time sleeping anyway, so you quite sure are looking for something cleverer.

I personally like the principle of queues; you could use e. g. a `std::deque` for:

Your producer thread places in some values, your consumer thread just takes them out. Of course, you need to protect your queue via a `std::mutex` (or by other appropriate means) against race conditions...

The consumer would be running in an endless loop, processing the queue, if entries are available, or sleep if this is not the case. Have a look at this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10975146/1312382) for how to do the waiting...

There is the danger, though, that your queue runs full, so you might define some threshold when you stop or at least slow down producing new values, if you discover your producer being too fast. The queue has another advantage, though: If your producer is too fast, you might have more than one consumer, all serving the same queue (depending on your needs, putting together the results might need some extra efforts to keep ordering of correct).

Admitted, that's quite some work to do, it might be worth the effort, it might be overkill. If simpler approaches fit your needs already, [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005354/1312382) answer is fine, too...