# How to wait for thread to retire in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Scenario:**

2 Threads executing a function **foo** called from inside function bar but **only one** at a time executes foo. Like call it T1 and T2.

T1 starts at some unknown time. It can be before OR after T2 starts.

T2 is called with force restart parameter. If this parameter is set, it should induce retire of  existing task(T1) , wait till it retires then move forward and execute himself.

Threads add themself into a global STL list to make sure only one can run at a time the foo function.

**How do we induce retire?**

Very simple global retire boolean flag and the foo is just 2 nested FOR loops. So at some point it will come across this check. if(retire) goto exit; and then the thread will come out of foo and close.

```
//All globals are guarded by locks and assignments are done via interlock 
//exchange. I am trying to solve the notification problem described 
//below. This is just a pseudo code.
bar(bool forcerestart)
{
    ...
    
    if(forcerestart && other_task_running_bar)
    g_forcerestart = 1;
    //some logic to handle retire of other thread.
    foo()
    ...
}

foo()
{
    for()
     for()
      if(g_forcerestart)
       goto exit;
 exit:
    g_forcerestart = 0;
}
```

**Question:**

How do I make T2(which is called with force restart) wait till T1 retires?

First solution: while(retire); <-- This is very CPU intensive if T1 takes a long time to retire.

Second solution: condition_variable(wait) <-- T1 will call notify when its about to finish.Like last statement.

**Problem** is , T2 doesn't know before entering the wait if T1 is already finished or not. Because if T1 is already finished , it would have called notify early, and the notification would be lost as T2 has not yet tried to acquire the lock.

I feel this is 2-party problem. if we have only 2 parties , none of them would know the exact live state of the other, so this cannot be solved via wait-signal. We need a CPU polling/retry policy to check plus threadid to know if the other thread is alive.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

**Update**:
I was trying to solve this problem without directly using lock/unlock.

**Answer**: Predicate parameter in C++11 condition variable.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

[image]

Thanks for your inputs everyone. Also thanks to the person who did -1 on this. Some folks just don't help but hinder.

Comment: why tag C when you're asking about C++?

Comment: Remember C++ *passes by value*, as in copies the values, so an argument will not be updated when the source variable is updated. You *must explicitly pass in by reference*.

Comment: Writing threaded code in C++ requires extreme attention to detail. What you have here makes a lot of wild presumptions about how things work and shows you need to read up more on the fundamentals here. Do you have a good reference for writing effective C++ multi-threaded code?

Comment: You will have to implement wait/signal structure between T1 & T2 through the mutex objects. You can check this thread to see if there is anything useful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974829/waiting-thread-until-a-condition-has-been-occurred

Comment: FWIW: Using a simple [yield](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) inside a ‘waiting while loop’ will *significantly* reduce CPU usage, often to the point of being inconsequential. Thread visibility still needs to be ensured, however it can be used for flags without additional signaling.

Comment: Very confusing question.  Did you mean for both functions to be called `bar`?  (It kind of looks like the second function is supposed to be called `foo`)

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.  The flag is fine.  Think of it like a "dad needs the family car" emergency.  If the car keys are on the rack, then no problem, just take the car.  If not then: 1) You ensure that when the car eventually comes back that you will get your turn next, then 2) text everyone that there's a stop-what-you're doing-emergency and whoever has the car needs to bring the car back ASAP, then 3) you wait for the car to come back.  As soon as the keys show up on the key rack, you take the keys, cancel the declaration of your emergency and off you go.

Comment: @user2864740, presumably that loop isn't a spin lock.  It's probably doing some useful work in the loop, and just checking between loop iterations if it's time to cancel.  No need to yield.

Comment: Unrelated, rather than `goto` place the nested `for` loops inside another function and replace the `goto exit;` with a plain old `return;`. Easy to read and fewer nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Predicate parameter in C++11 condition variable. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait