# unexpected delay in main thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Here is a small c++ code to test cyclic call using thread. But it gets failed because of unexpected delay sometimes. The for-loop should be called every 10ms. The runtime of for-loop is just 1ms usually. But sometimes the execution time is longer than 200ms. It looks like other process interrupts this for-loop and return back after 200ms. This is unbelievable, 200ms, so long time is taken. The program runs under GNU Linux 5.10.41 ARM aarch64.
How can I do, so that the main thread can not be preemptive by other process or threads ? Thanks a lot!

```
while(1)
{
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    LOG_F(INFO, "cyclic start time");
    for(int j = 0; j < 150000; j++); //
    auto end_time  = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto exec_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    LOG_F(INFO, "execution time: %dms", exec_time.count());
    if (exec_time.count() < 10)
    {
        LOG_F(INFO, "i = %d", i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10 - exec_time.count()));
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_F(ERROR, "execution time was higher than 10ms (%dms)", exec_time.count());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use a higher priority thread or a real time thread. Those are less likely to be peemted. However normally if your system is not under heavy load, your program should not be preemted for 200ms

Comment: What is the purpose of `for(int j = 0; j < 150000; j++);`? It will be optimized away. You are just measuring the logging function's time cost.

Comment: Shot in the dark. Logging mutex hog. There likely is a mutex/lock within your logging system. Another thread may be a resource hog acquiring the lock and not releasing it quickly. This would cause THIS thread to wait much longer than expected. Check this behaviour by disabling all other threads and see if behaviour continues.

Comment: quick test, move all the logging statements outside of where you capture `start_time` and `end_time`. As alluded to earlier, also make sure you're compiling _without_ optimizations if you want that `for` loop to do anything. But even counting to 150000 should happen extremely fast, probably in the microsecond order of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proposals. The for-loop was executed, no optimization. Changing the loop number the runtime is also different in log file. The program was running on a S32G EVB with 4 processors. Using top command I can see the CPU load = 4.3%. Even if the thread function sleep() in the code is used, but actually only one main thread.

Comment: @yano, I can not really follow you. What you mean "move all the logging statements outside of where you capture start_time and end_time" actually ?

Comment: You are asking too much of a desktop/server/mobile-device operating system if you need such precise timing. Only a [_real-time OS_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) can provide the precision that you want.

Comment: I mean don't have any logging statements in between `auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` and `auto end_time  = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();`. Particularly if `LOG_F` prints to the screen, that can take a long time. 200ms sounds excessive, but all I was suggesting was capture your start and end time without a logging statement to see if that's slowing things down. Altho now I've re-read your question and you say it only takes 1ms most of the time, so my suggestion is probably useless.

Comment: @yano, I will try to remove the logging statements. Maybe this is problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Solomon, this program was working well on Ubuntu Linux which is also no real time Os. I don't need so precise cyclic timing, a deviation of 20% even 30% is acceptable, but not longer than 200ms. Here is something wrong, I would like to understand.

Comment: @Frebreeze, you are right. The logging is a mutex hog.

Comment: @Jung, Sorry, I wasn't trying to answer _why_ your program encountered the 200ms delay. And, you are right; depending on your needs, you may be able to meet real-time goals with software running on a non real-time OS. I only wanted to point out that if you need _guaranteed_ real-time performance, that's what real-time operating systems are for.

Comment: @Solomon, Thanks a lot for your care about this issue. I have written the facing issue and need help from all of you and all different ideas. I appreciate your support. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is working after remove logging statements. Logging is really a mutex hog like @Frebreeze mentioned. Actually the logging statements can be kept in code, just call program with -v ERROR. Thank you very much for the Help !

It looks that the logging is the reason. But why does the logging statements take so long time, but not always, just like a heartbeat ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer written in original answer in comments:

> Shot in the dark. Logging mutex hog. There likely is a mutex/lock
> within your logging system. Another thread may be a resource hog
> acquiring the lock and not releasing it quickly. This would cause THIS
> thread to wait much longer than expected. Check this behaviour by
> disabling all other threads and see if behaviour continues.

Follow up help below:

@Jung Glad you figured it out!

If logging is taking variable amounts of time, look into the data you are passing to the logging system. General things to lookout for would be large data structs passed by value. Yes I know compilers are smart now, but just something to keep an eye out for.

One of the methods I sometimes use to reduce log hogs is to use a dedicated thread for writing log statements to file. This thread uses a std::vector or queue. When vector.size() > 8, then dump it to the file(s). If you have a method of setting priority, you can then also then assign prio. This gets us into RTOS ideas. Can look into that if you need strict timings.

Workflow

- Suppose sensor1 thread writes log statement.

  - Sensor1 thread adds data to std::vec
- Suppose sensor2 thread writes log statement

  - Sensor2 thread adds data to std::vec

....

- Once std::vec > 8 [fire event to wake up thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974829/waiting-thread-until-a-condition-has-been-occurred)
- Thread wakes up, and once given CPU time, begins writing to file

This will help minimize the time spent locking mutexs as well as minimize time spent opening files. However, it is at the cost of memory. Play with the queue size to reach your desired goals.

Comment: Hi @Frebreeze, Thanks. I will try this and put results here if I get some interesting.

Comment: great, it is working also if logging statement has own thread and uses queue according to your idea.

Comment: Glad things seem to be working for you!